# Program crashing after button onClick

Tags: java, android

Not sure what's wrong here. The crash happens if there is nothing in the edittext spots. It works if they are all filled out. So my problem is the `if` statement check. It is going into the `if` statement even if the edittexts are empty. It is supposed to skip to the `else` and log that not all fields are completed.

The problem is here (I think) - it is jumping into the loop even though it is not supposed to:

```
//Calculate Risk Score Button

Button calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcButton);

calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Create and set values
        int smoker = 0;
        int medicated = 0;
        char gender = 'm';
        String selectedAge = (String) ageSpin.getSelectedItem();
        Log.i("TEST", "Before if");

        if (selectedAge != null
                && cholEdit.getText().toString() != null
                && hdlEdit.getText().toString() != null
                && sbpEdit.getText().toString() != null
                && genderGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1
                && smokerGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1
                && medsGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
        Log.i("TEST", "After if");

            // store values
            int age = Integer.parseInt(selectedAge.toString());
            int chol = Integer.parseInt(cholEdit.getText().toString());
            int hdl = Integer.parseInt(hdlEdit.getText().toString());
            int sbp = Integer.parseInt(sbpEdit.getText().toString());
            int genderId = genderGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            int smokeId = smokerGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            int medsId = medsGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // Set gender, smoker and if medicated values
            if (genderId == R.id.maleR)
                gender = 'm';
            else if (genderId == R.id.femaleR)
                gender = 'f';

            if (smokeId == R.id.yesR)
                smoker = 1;
            else if (smokeId == R.id.noR)
                smoker = 0;

            if (medsId == R.id.yesR2)
                medicated = 1;
            else if (medsId == R.id.yesR2)
                medicated = 0;

            // Calculate Answer and Print
            String answer = calc.calculateRiskScore(age, gender, chol,
                    smoker, hdl, sbp, medicated);


            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
                    PREF_FILE, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

            editor.putInt("age", age);
            editor.putInt("chol", chol);
            editor.putInt("hdl", hdl);
            editor.putInt("sbp", sbp);
            editor.putInt("gender", genderId);
            editor.putInt("smoker", smoker);
            editor.putInt("med", medicated);
            editor.putString("risk", answer);

            editor.commit();

            displayRisk(answer);
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Not all fields are completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the logcat error. I get what the error is saying, but it should not be in the `if` statement to make it:

```
04-22 21:26:43.920: I/TEST(22544): Before if
04-22 21:26:43.920: I/TEST(22544): After if
04-22 21:26:43.920: W/dalvikvm(22544): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41634438)
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at edu.auburn.eng.csse.comp3710.group04.CardiovascularActivity$1.onClick(CardiovascularActivity.java:83)
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4198)
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17164)
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: 82 int age = Integer.parseInt(selectedAge.toString());     83 int chol = Integer.parseInt(cholEdit.getText().toString());

Comment: Ah you are parsing an empty String. hqt's answer would work, you should really handle the error better than that though. I would create a validation() function that is called when the button is pressed and doesn't continue until all the fields have valid ints in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Exception has thrown :

```
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
04-22 21:26:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22544):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
```

The problem is : `TextField` that you use to get text, and parse int. because this textfield is empty (you should remember, empty is very different to `NULL`).  `TextField` itself, is not null, but the text you get is empty (`""`). So, `Integer.parseInt` will throw exception in this case. (does not automatically return 0 as we wish) So, in the code, you must surround by `try-catch` block for all `Integer.parseInt` method in your program, to prevent some silly input from user.

```
int chol = 0;
int hdl = 0;
int age = 0;
try {

                    age = Integer.parseInt(selectedAge.toString());
                    chol = Integer.parseInt(cholEdit.getText().toString());
                    hdl = Integer.parseInt(hdlEdit.getText().toString());

}

catch (Exception e) {
     chol = 0;
     hdl = 0;
     age = 0;
}
```

And this is a best pattern when you use `Integer.parseInt` or `Double.parseDouble` ...

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than check for "!= null", you should check for isNullOrEmpty (write such a method which checks if the "string == null || string.isEmpty()" as apparently those toString methods are return empty strings ("") and Integer.parseInt barfs on empty strings the same as it would on the string "hello".

Comment: Hmm I would have checked that but it was working earlier this way... Thats why im so confused. If it were to barf on empty strings would that cause it to jump into the if?

Comment: Because your if statements are only checking for "!= null" they are letting empty strings pass through as those are not null.